# suitable versioning for chaotic development

Tags: svn, version-control

During a few years I've been devloping a framework that's quite capable, (just added a library for serving webapps with zepto and it performs very well.)

I'm about to publish it on github or launchpad and currently trying to find a workflow where the versioning doesn't get in the way.

I want the versioning to be as clever as possible with minimal actions required. Adding / renaming files, yet remain the versioning should be a no-brainer. Possible?

Thankful for any clever setups. Development host:  windows. IDE: PHPStorm

thanks
//t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- PHPStorm support [VCS inside IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/enabling-version-control.html)
- PHPStorm have a [long list of supported systems](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/supported-version-control-systems.html)

You can try all (except CVS, I hope) *VCS and define, which is better *for you*, but in the light of

> be as clever as possible with minimal actions required

I'll suggest SVN or Mercurial, there Mercurial is more (*for me*) preferable way (natural merge).

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Idiot topic but heavy lack of time. Thanks.

Comment: Can see **nothing** idiotic. Normal (usual) process, reasonable reqs